# What is causing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot and I get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in cmd.exe` while I run the discord bot, can anyone tell me what I did wrong or if I need to show more code?

```
let pUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

{some code here}

let pCoins = userData[pUser.id].money;
```

Comment: `pUser` is undefined - add `console.log(typeof pUser)` after the `let pUser` line ... is it undefined?

Comment: yes it is still undefined

Comment: so, you need to find why neither `message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())` nor `message.guild.members.get(args[0])` return what you want - and since I don't know what `message` is I can't help

Comment: ... we also don't know what args is. Please clarify this! :)

Comment: args is ```const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");

const args = messageArray.slice(1);``` and "message" is the persons message on discord

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
let pUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
```

add a:

```
if(!pUser) return message.channel.send('You need to provide a valid mention or user id!');
```

This will stop the rest of the command if no user was found, and so will stop the error from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `pUser` is `undefined`. Since it is defined as such:

```js
let pUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
```

and `undefined` coerces to a false boolean, that means that `message.guild.members.get(args[0])` (the right side part of the OR statement) evaluates to `undefined`. I think that a possible cause for that is the user ID passed as `args[0]` in your command doesn't match any members in the guild.